# Touch on an object and score increment does not working

Tags: libgdx, touch

I have an array of coins.I increment the score on touch of a coin.

```
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        game.camera.unproject(touchPos);
        for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
            Rectangle textureBounds = new Rectangle(coins[i].getX(), coins[i].getY(), coins[i].getWidth(),
                    coins[i].getHeight());

            if (textureBounds.contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y)/* && !coins[i].isTapBool()*/) {
           System.out.println("touched");

                coins[i].setTapBool(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Increments score like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        if (coins[i].isTapBool()&&coins[i].isCoinVisible()) {

            coinScoreController.updateCoinScore(delta);//score=score+1
            coins[i].setTapBool(false);
        }
    coins[i].isTapBool());
    }
```

Now each time when I touch a coin score increments by 13 not 1.The print statement inside the if condition for tap also prints 13 times.
I want to increment score by 1 only.
How to solve this?What I did wrong in the code?

Comment: I may be wrong but we need more information to help you with this. What is the `coins` array made of? I imagine is a custom class, since you call the setTapBool method on it. So probably the issue is that you're making the rectangle with getX, getY etc. on this custom class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after changing Gdx.input.isTouched() to Gdx.input.justTouched().